# Очистка содержимого элементов с подходящим ID

Tags: html, javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку 'Очистить 13 марта' очищалось содержимое span'a, у которых ID заканчивается на '2015-03-13'?

```js
  function ZZZ() {
    document.getElementById("1.2015-03-13").textContent = ""; /* Там где 1 - любое число */
  }
```

```html
<span id="1.2015-03-13">5</span>
<span id="1.2015-03-14">5</span>
<span id="1.2015-03-15">5</span>
<span id="2.2015-03-13">5</span>
<span id="2.2015-03-14">5</span>
<span id="2.2015-03-15">5</span>
<input type="button" onclick="ZZZ();" value="Очистить 13 марта">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно  вот так http://jsfiddle.net/7z5gfn81/